# Laravel: Not able to pass the right parameter to route in DataTable Buttons

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables, laravel-blade

I was using the normal tables and all my buttons where working fine. Then I came accross DataTables and so I have implemented datatables to list all the employees in my employees model.
So i use JQuery to give data to my table. Below is the code:

```
   $(document).ready( function () {
        $('.table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax : '{!! route('employees.search') !!}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                { data: 'empid', name: 'empid'},
                { data: 'user_type', name: 'user_type'},
                { data: 'depots', name: 'depots'},
                { data: 'id',   name: 'id',
                  render: function ( data , row ) {
                    return '<div style="margin-left:1%;">
                            <button class="btn btn-round btn-primary btn-sm" 
                             onclick="showMessage('+data+')">Delete</button> 
                             <form id="'+data+'" method="POST" action=" {{ 
                              route("employees.destroy","'+data+'") }} "> 
                              <input type="hidden" name="_method" 
                               value="delete"> {{ csrf_field() }} </form> </div>';
                    }
                },
            ],
        });
    });
```

So in the code above I have rendered a button to perform the Delete function.
Somehow when i pass the paramater to my route {{ `route("employees.destroy","'+data+'") }}` it returns as **data** while i'm expecting it to be the id of the row. Below is my code for delete function:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        return $id;
        if ( Auth::check() ) {
            $findResult = AppUser::where('id','=',$id)->first();
            $user = User::where('email',$findResult->email)->first();
            if ($findResult->delete())
            { 
                if ($user) {
                    $user->delete();
                }
                return redirect()->route('employees.index','all')->with('success' , 'Employee deleted successfully!');
            }
            return back()->withInput()->with('error' , 'Employee could not be deleted');
        }        
    }
```

So the response I get is wrong. Can someone please tell me an alternative or solution to send the paramater to the route? I'm expecting the value to be the id of the row but the response i get is just **'+data+'**.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

1. Return URL as part of the data using [`addColumn()`](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/add-column) method. For example:

   ```
   // ... skipped ...
   ->addColumn('delete_url', function ($model) {
       return route('backend.model.delete', $model);
   });
   ```
2. Give "Delete" button a special class, for example "btn-delete".
3. Attach event handler to "Delete" button by using special class "btn-delete". When button is clicked make Ajax request using URL from `delete_url` data property.